# Why does dateGmt() function contains a Time quotient at all?

Tags: soql, datetime, date

```
Long startTime = 1112222220;
Date startDate  = DateTime.newInstance(Long.valueOf(startTime)).dateGmt();
system.debug('startDate: '+startDate);
String qry = 'Select Id, Subject from Task where ActivityDate > :startDate';
system.debug('qry: '+qry.replace(':startDate', ''+startDate));
```

**The above prints the debug as:**

> startDate: 1973-07-11 00:00:00
>
> qry: Select Id, Subject from Task where ActivityDate > 1973-07-11 00:00:00

It seems to contain the time portion and I do not get any Task records as part of my query. SO as I understand, I got a Date variable and I also extracted correct Date and assigned it. Then used it in a SOQL variable appropriately, but still something is not right, I might be ignoring something small, but impactful in my understanding, so need some guidance what might be wrong here in my understanding.

If I remove the time portion from startDate variable manually, my Query returns appropriate number of Task records.

Comment: Do you want to put just date in the query like `1973-07-11`??

Comment: yes that is right. I actually expected date variable to NOT contain anything for a time portion at all, doesnt make sense to me, why it would do.

Comment: Actually the date always contains time but its fixed to `00:00:00`.

Comment: try this `String strdate = DateTime.newInstance(startTime ).format('yyyy-MM-dd');`

Answer (score 0):

dateGmt() returns the Date component of a Datetime in the GMT time zone.

What you are looking for is format(). You need to format your date literal to a SOQL expected syntax.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm

YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm

YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ

Comment: That is right. I know but I am looking to understand why even after assigning to a DATE type variable and returning date only from function dateGmt() would still contain a Time portion. It does not make sense to me.

Comment: Date class in SF contains the time portion as well but it is always points to midnight since midnight is the start of the day. `dateGMT`, `date` and , `Date.newInstance` from the structure perspective are the same. 

DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(2006, 3, 16, 23, 0, 0);
Date myDate = myDateTime.dateGMT();
Date expected = Date.newInstance(2006, 3, 17);
System.debug('Dates'+myDate+'=='+expected);
System.assertEquals(expected, myDate);